# I receive Error: Pixel project matrix not invertible and this.state.viewport for map does not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have Geocoder component for mapbox(see Map.jsx file) and when I search for example(type in search input) 'Kyiv', it works well, but 'Kenya' does not, and throws an error in console.
I use react-map-gl-geocoder in my project 
Here is link to my code: https://github.com/NetisGod/Viewpoints-issue

I can't understand why some cities work, but another doesn't

Error that throws in console:

```
Uncaught Error: Pixel project matrix not invertible
    at WebMercatorViewport.Viewport (bundle.js:93669)
    at new WebMercatorViewport (bundle.js:94106)
    at fitBounds (bundle.js:88838)
    at EventEmitter.Geocoder._this.handleResult (bundle.js:88997)
    at EventEmitter../node_modules/events/events.js.EventEmitter.emit (bundle.js:8857)
    at MapboxGeocoder._onChange (bundle.js:1932)
    at Suggestions../node_modules/suggestions/src/suggestions.js.Suggestions.value (bundle.js:143620)
    at List../node_modules/suggestions/src/list.js.List.handleMouseUp (bundle.js:143415)
    at List.<anonymous> (bundle.js:143409)
```

I need to make Geocoder search for mapbox work properly.

Comment: Are you sure it is passing into fit bound a bbox in the correct order and with coordinates within the bounds of web mercator lat long?

Answer (score -1):

The solution was strange. Interestingly enough, I had set a height and width on the MapGL component and it looks like removing this and adding it in the viewport state object fixed my issue.

Comment: You should show source code for your answer to help explain what caused the issue and the fix to give context to your explanation.